# cmd batch file check if current hour is equal to one of specific hour

Tags: datetime, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I would like to develop a batch file to check the current time hour is equal to specific hour.

As long as n+2 hour (e.g. 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, etc...) is matched with system current hour, it will echo to valid message, otherwise it will echo to invalid message.

Anyone can help me? Thanks.

**Source Code**

```
FOR /F %%a IN ('Powershell -Nop -c "Get-Date -Format 'HH'"') DO SET getcurrHour=%%a
FOR /L %%a IN (0,2,22) DO SET hourList=%%a
    
IF %getcurrHour% == %hourList% (
    
    ECHO It's valid.
    
) ELSE (
    
    ECHO It's not valid.
)
```

Comment: Powershell is more powerful than batch processing. Why do you use batch processing for evaluating Powershell results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using PowerShell anyhow, then let it do more of the work for you.

```sh
@%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile^
 "$Hr = (Get-Date).Hour;"^
 "If (((($Hr / 2) - [Math]::Truncate($Hr / 2)) * 10) -Eq 5)"^
 "{ Write-Host \"It's not valid.\" }"^
 "Else { Write-Host \"It's valid.\" }"
@Pause
```

*The `@Pause` is included only for users testing directly from the GUI, for others it can be omitted*

---

Just to reduce the amount of code I used to prove a point, here's a more specific example for the task you've laid out in your question, i.e. determining whether the hour is odd or even:

```sh
@powershell.exe -NoP "If (((Get-Date).Hour %% 2) -Eq 1) { Write-Host \"It's not valid.\" } Else { Write-Host \"It's valid.\" }"
@Pause
```

*Once again the pause is only required for users invoking the batch file via the GUI.*

---

And because inevitably, you're going to tell us that you're not really wanting to print messages to the screen, but to perform different actions based upon the odd or even result:

```sh
@For /F %%G In ('powershell.exe -NoP "(Get-Date).Hour %% 2"') Do @If %%G Equ 1 (Echo It's not valid) Else Echo It's Valid.
@Pause
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and teach me how to do so!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to test each value in the loop, not set the last value and test.
There is another issue however. `Powershell`'s date is returned as `HH` which will do:

```
02
etc
22
```

Where your `for /L` loop gives:

```
2
etc
22
```

Meaning for some numbers it will not be true. So we need to test if the loop is single digit or double, if single we add  a leading `0`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%a in ('Powershell -Nop -c "Get-Date -Format 'HH'"') do set "getcurrHour=%%a"
for /L %%a IN (0,2,22) do (
   set "li=%%~a"
   if "!li:~1!" == "" set "li=0!li!"
   if %getcurrHour% equ !li! (
       echo It's valid.
     ) else (
       echo It's not valid.
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F %%a IN ('Powershell -Nop -c "Get-Date -Format 'HH'"') DO SET getcurrHour=%%a
set /a "check=(1%getcurrhour%-100) %%2"
if "%check%" == "0" (
  echo even hour
) else (
  echo odd hour
)
```

I guess, the line `set /a "check=(1%getcurrhour%-100) %%2` needs some explanation:

`set /a` also knows octal numbers. They start with a zero. `08` and `09` start with a zero, but are not valid octal numbers, so we would get a syntax error. So we precede it with a `1` and subtract `100` from that to get a valid decimal number (`8`) The we simply do a `MOD 2` to get a zero for even numbers and a one for odd numbers.